# One linked list for python using C api

Tags: python, c, pointers, data-structures, cpython

I'm trying to make one linked list for Python using C api. 
This stuff works:

```
typedef struct list {
    int item;
    struct list *next;
} list;

void insert(list **self, int item) {
    list *p = malloc(sizeof(list));
    p->item = item;
    p->next = *self;
    *self = p;
}

int main() {
    list *myList = NULL;
    insert(&myList, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

but Python C api use *self, instead **self. So, how can it works, if insert function would be like this:

```
void insert(list *self, int item) {
```

Comment: in the example you show, the function `insert` takes a pointer to a pointer to a `list`. The first pointer is then dereferenced, to read and then change the pointer that points to the `list` structure. Are you asking how to do this same read & change if a pointer to a list structure (`list *self`) is passed to the function, instead of a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: Yes. I want to send myList into insert without ampersand

Comment: the solution for what you want, is to access using `self` instead of `*self`, i.e. `p->next = self;`, but that also means that by doing `self = p;` on the next line, you are only modifying your function's copy of that pointer, and the caller won't see the change. The way to get around this is by passing a pointer to a pointer, like in the code you showed. What exactly is it you need to do?

Comment: is there possible to caller to see the changes?

Comment: As I understand, myList is a pointer with value of address to the first element of the structure. Can I change this value to another element of that structure?

Comment: the values passed into your function are copies. any changes you make to them will only be visible inside your function. So, yes, you can do whatever you want to `myList`, but if you're in a function then those changes won't be seen by the caller. If you need to change something in a function, the usual approach is to pass a pointer-- see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just drop the `*`, i.e.:

```
void insert(list *self, int item) {
    list *p = malloc(sizeof(list));
    p->item = item;
    p->next = self;
    self = p;
}
```

But I don't think this will behave like you expect, because the line `self = p` will not actually modify the same pointer that the caller was using. Your function gets a seperate copy of `*self` when it runs (C is [pass-by-value](http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/20/is-c-pass-by-value-or-reference)). If you want to modify something in a function and have the caller see the change, the normal approach is to use a pointer-- so you don't need to modify the copy of the pointer passed into the function, but you can use it to access the same piece of memory that the caller has been working with. In your case, the caller is working with a pointer to `myList`, so if you want the function to change the value of that pointer, you need a pointer to a pointer i.e. `list **self`.